# Ambiguity in disk space allocation for docker containers

Tags: docker

I have two Physical machine installed with Docker 1.11.3 on ubuntu. Following is the configuration of machines -
1. Machine 1 - RAM 4 GB, Hard disk - 500 GB, quad core
2. Machine 2 - RAM 8 GB, Hard disk - 1 TB, octa core

I created containers on both machines. When I check the disk space of individual containers, here are some stats, which I am not able to undestand the reason behind.

**1. Container on Machine 1**

```
root@e1t2j3k45432#df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             37G   27G  8.2G  77% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9        37G   27G  8.2G  77% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

- I have nothing installed in the above container, still it is showing
  27 GB used.
- How come this container got 37 GB of space. ?

**2. Container on Machine 2**

```
root@0af8ac09b89c:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            184G   11G  164G   6% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       184G   11G  164G   6% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

- Why only 11GB of disk space is shown as used in this container. Even
  though this is also empty container with no packages installed.
- How come this container is given 184 GB of disk space ?

Comment: did you use the same run command on both of them ? do you have the same docker daemon startup parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

The disk usage reported inside docker is the host disk usage of /var/lib/docker (my /var/lib/docker in the example below is symlinked to my /home where I have more disk space):

```
bash$ df -k /var/lib/docker/.
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/...      720798904 311706176 372455240  46% /home


bash$ docker run --rm -it busybox df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
none                 720798904 311706268 372455148  46% /
...
```

So if you run the df command on the same container on different hosts, a different result is expect.